# Create drop-down list from user input

Tags: javascript

Let me simplify the question this way. There are 2 tables in the document. The 1st table is requires input from user. Max length is 8 characters. 
The 2nd table is readonly. It contains a selection with 3 options. We want to do this: 
    User input in (1st table) cell1 = (2nd table) Option1 in the select element
    User input in (1st table) cell2 = (2nd table) Option2 in the select element
    User input in (1st table) cell3 = (2nd table) Option3 in the select element
However I can't achieve this. Where are my errors?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Thermo Analysis</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif; margin-left: 50px; 
max-width: 600px;}
th {font-size: 14px; border: 1px; border-style: solid; border-colapse:   
colapse; border-spacing: 0px;}
td {font-size: 14px; border: 1px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px; 
border-colapse: colapse; border-spacing: 0px;}
input:focus {background-color: rgb(255,255,150);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="imp">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Grade</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="8" onkeyup="implist((this));" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="8" onkeyup="implist((this));" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="8" onkeyup="implist((this));" /></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<table id="impData">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>System</th>
<th>Thermo-Category</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Thermo-Kinetics</td>
<td>
<select>
  <option input type="text"></option>
  <option input type="text"></option>
  <option input type="text"></option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<script>
function implist() {
var table = document.getElementById("imp");
var valOne = table.rows[1].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
var valTwo= table.rows[2].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
var valThree = table.rows[3].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")
[0].value;

var optionOne = valOne.slice(0, 3);
var optionTwo = "";     var optionThree = "";
var optionTwo = valTwo.slice(0, 3);
if (optionTwo === optionOne) {
    optionTwo = optionTwo + "1";
   }
var optionThree = valThree.slice(0, 3);
if (optionThree !== "" && optionThree === optionOne) {
    optionThree = optionThree + "2";
} else if (optionThree !== "" && optionThree === optionTwo) {
    optionThree = optionThree + "1";
}

var tble = document.getElementById("impData");
tble.rows[1].cells[1].selects[0].["option"][0].["input"][0].value =   
optionOne;
tble.rows[1].cells[1].selects[0].["option"][1].["input"][0].value =   
optionTwo;
tble.rows[1].cells[1].selects[0].["option"][2].["input"][0].value =  
optionThree;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly you need to fix your console errors: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`. Also a general tip, it's a good idea to have more meaningful variable names.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `e.rows[1].cells[1].selects[0].["option"][0].["input"][0].value`? It ends with the `option` element, in which to do that you cannot use `selects` you would do this: `e.rows[1].cells[1].firstChild.nextSibling[0]`. That will fix that problem. But what `input` are you trying to get?

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek. Thanks for your support. I have edited my initial submission to simply the issue. Precisely how to dynamically generate a select element with 3 options from user inputs.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek Your suggestion works perfect. I appreciate.